# Apache solr is not accessible by my server but accessible by my localhost

Tags: solr, centos6.5

I have a solr installed in my server(centos 6.5).and everything works fine and my conf files exist where they should be. I try to connect to solr by help of [search_api_solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module in drupal. Everything works fine on my localhost and one other host I try my website on,but when I try to connect to this solr using a website on the same server as the solr I'm get error

> The Solr server could not be reached

where should I start looking for something that went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was caused by selinux on my server.

by disabling selinux and rebooting centOs I could connect to my solr apache.